# SAXON Error- How to ignore/skip it?

Tags: javascript, xslt, batch-processing, saxon

Using Saxon HE (net version) wget and batch, I'm trying to transform a page I've downloaded via wget.

Whenever calling the command on the page, I get the following error:

> SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The entity name must
>   immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

It is related to a line in a VERY awkward line of javescript. However, I have no control about the page I am wanting to transform, so I can't do anything against this error on that side.

Is there any way to tell Saxon to skip such errors? I would not mind if it would drop the entire tag, since I'm not looking to read any data from the javascript elements.

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, it is an error reported by the underlying XML parser that Saxon uses to parse the markup of the document you are providing to it. If that is not well-formed XML then any XML parser will reject it. Saxon offers you [the choice to use an HTML tag soup parser like TagSoup](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.5/using-xsl/commandline.html) instead by calling it with the option `-x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser` if you put TagSoup from http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/ on the class path.

Comment: Cannot/don't want to use TagSoup since I try to avoid Java for this purpose (using the net version of Saxon), but your hint got me to the right way to find "xmllint" which apparently does quite the same successfully (even if it needs to be called separately on the file).
Thank you very much!